# PHP Array Explode Twice

Tags: php, arrays, oracle

I have an array which I need to insert into multiple rows of database. The structure of array is like:

```
$var = "Name1,Age1,DOB1,Relation1.Name2,Age2,Dob2,Relation2.";//And so on, depending on users input
```

(Dot indicates new line whereas Comma indicates new column)
I need to insert it into database like this:

**I first stored all rows in an array like:**

```
$rowsToInsert = explode (".",$var);
```

**I have now:**

```
$rowsToInsert[0] = Name1,Age1,DOB1,Relation1;
$rowsToInsert[1] = Name2,Age2,DOB2,Relation2; 
...And So on...
```

**Problem:**

What is the fastest way to store these array elements into database having Name, Age, DOB, Relation columns?

Answer (score 1):

May be this will work

```
$rows = explode (".",$var);
$addslash = addslashes($rows);

foreach($addslash as $val) {
    $val_str = str_replace("," ,"','", $val);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (Name, Age, DOB, Relation) VALUES ('" .$val_str. "')";
}
```