# Explode String twice using PHP

Tags: php, explode

I have seen two similar questions on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763004/exploding-a-string-twice) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796779/php-array-explode-twice) but still stuck...

I have a string of filepath like `catalog/reviews/249532-20691-5369.jpg` and i want to get numbers only like `249532-20691-5369`.

I am using the following approach:

```
$id1 = explode('/', $image['img_link']);
$id2 = explode('.', $id1[2]);
echo $id2;  //output 249532-20691-5369
```

Is there any best approach to do this task in controller.

Comment: If the string is always in that form, this is a fine way of doing ths. If the string is ever different, regex may be a better option of the length of the numbers is always the same.

Comment: You could use a regex if you really want to, but if what you have works for you, why worry.

Comment: yes...always same lenght...

Comment: @JonStirling, I am not much fimilar with regex

Comment: @MuhammadHashirAnwaar Then stick with what you know?

Comment: If you want to check the full path.

`$image['img_link'] = "catalog/reviews/249532-20691-5369.jpg";
 $id1 = explode('/', $image['img_link']);
 // loop to check array
 foreach($id1 as $id) {
     if (preg_match('~[0-9]+~', $id)) {
         // string with numbers
         $id2 = explode('.',$id); 
}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://ideone.com/XGwrTc

```
echo basename($image['img_link'], '.jpg');
```

an alternative if you have different file extensions:

```
echo pathinfo ( $image['img_link'] ,  PATHINFO_FILENAME );
```

Comment: Beautifully simple!

Comment: But that still contains the .jpg file extension

Comment: @Philipp check updated

Comment: @Philipp No, this doesn't contain the extension

Comment: @executable his first posted version didn't remove the suffix

Comment: what if extension is dynamic.... means...some images will have .jpg others will have .png or else... then how can i handle that

Comment: @MuhammadHashirAnwaar check updated

Comment: Worked...Bravo !

Comment: @MuhammadHashirAnwaar If it worked, then you should accept the answer.

Comment: @Alex , Accepted... (Y)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you could use a simple regular expression.

```
([^\/]+)\.jpg$
```

And in php this would look like this

```
preg_match('/([^\/]+)\.jpg$/', $image['img_link'], $m);
echo $m[1];
```

If you need it for any extension, you could use this

```
([^\/]+)\.[^\.]+$
```

So how does this work:

We start from the right, so we add an anchor to the line ending `$`. From there on, we want the extension, which is practically everything expect a point `[^\.]+`. Whats left is the file name, which is everything from the point until you reach the slash `[^\/]+`. This part is also enclosed in a capturing group `()` to access it in the end with `$m[1]`.

Comment: Great, thanks! The only thing I can think of that would make your answer even better is a breakdown of how the regex works, but obviously that's up to you.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton better?

Answer (score 0):

`explode` returns an array, so you need to access the first element:

```
$ids = explode('/', $image['img_link'];
$id2 = explode('.', end($ids));

echo $id2[0];
```

Alternatively, you can just use `basename()` instead of the first `explode()` (assuming you always have `.jpg` extension):

```
echo basename($image['img_link'], '.jpg');
```

Comment: if extension is dynamic then???

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex

This pattern would work:

```
(\d{6}-\d{5}-\d{4})
```

Breakdown:

- `\d` means "Any Digit"
- `{#}` means a count of # values, and of course the dashes between the numbers.
- Wrap the whole thing with parenthesis to capture the whole result

Code:

```
$string = "catalog/reviews/249532-20691-5369.jpg";

preg_match('(\d{6}-\d{5}-\d{4})', $string, $result);
echo $result[0];
```

Output:

```
249532-20691-5369
```